# Python – Debugging and visualizing a regex

Tags: python, regex, fuzzy-search

I am using the [regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) in Python to perform fuzzy searches, such as the following :

```
expreg = regex.compile(f'(?e)(Fibonacci){{i<=1,s<=1,d<=1}}')
result = regex.search(expreg, 'FMbo nacc')
```

I have written the following snippet of code to make sense of what the methods `match.fuzzy_counts` and `match.fuzzy_changes` output :

```
def visualize(match_object):

    if match_object is None:
        return None

    start, end = match_object.span(0)
    match_text = match_object[0]
    length_text = len(match_text)
    substitutions = [i - start for i in match_object.fuzzy_changes[0]]
    insertions = [i - start for i in match_object.fuzzy_changes[1]]
    deletions = [i - start for i in match_object.fuzzy_changes[2]]
    print (match_object)
    print (f'fuzzy_changes : {substitutions}, {insertions}, {deletions}')

    # Examine first substitutions and insertions
    visualizer = ''
    for i in range(length_text):
        if i in substitutions:
            visualizer += f'[{match_text[i]}]'
        elif i in insertions:
            visualizer += rf'{{{match_text[i]}}}'
        else:
            visualizer += f'{match_text[i]}'

    # Then deletions
    total_transformations = 0
    for i, deletion in enumerate(deletions):
        previous = 0 if i == 0 else deletions[i - 1]
        intermediate_substitutions = len(
            [w for w in substitutions if previous <= w and w < deletion])
        intermediate_insertions = len(
            [y for y in insertions if previous <= y and y < deletion])
        total_transformations += intermediate_substitutions + intermediate_insertions
        visualizer = f'{visualizer[:deletion + i + (total_transformations*2):]}<>{visualizer[deletion + i + (total_transformations*2)::]}'

    print (f'regex : {result.re}\nvisualizer : {visualizer}')
```

When applied to the match object result, defined above, it prints the following string : F[M]bo{ }nacc<> (where brackets indicate substitutions, curly braces insertions, and <> deletions).

Now, I would like to find a way to know, in case I look for a list of alternatives, say f'(?e)(Fibonacci|Pound|Fulano){{i<=1,s<=1,d<=1}}', which name is responsible for the match and retrieve it. In other words, is it possible to unlock the regex blackbox ? Of course I am aware of websites like regex101, but it would be nice to use that piece of information in my Python script itself.

I have read many SO questions pertaining to the same topic, but none of them yields a satisfactory answer. Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!